# Does a clock oscillator require a load?

Tags: oscillator

I want to use this clock oscillator

http://www.ecsxtal.com/store/pdf/ecs-2100x.pdf

It does not require loading capacitance.

However, it says "3.3V operation (optional)", yet on the same page it says "Supply Voltage: 5VDC +/- 0.25".

I was considering just throwing it in a breadboard, giving it 3.3V, and scoping the output pin to see if it worked.  But I was wondering if I would have any problems since the output pin would be unloaded, except for the scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I often check oscillators like that without a load. You might notice some ringing on the edges.

The optional 3.3V means that they can supply a low-voltage version.

I've occasionally used a 5V CMOS oscillator at 3.3V in a prototype when I haven't had a suitable 3.3V device, they've always worked.

Comment: There is nothing in the datasheet or on digikey's parametric search that indicates this part has a low-voltage version.  The only alternate part numbers control for the frequency stability.

Comment: You have to order the low-voltage version from the supplier, as a non-standard item. It will probably be more expensive. Plenty of 3.3V oscillators are available as standard items.

Comment: I tried giving it 3.3V and it oscillated quite happy at the correct frequency.  And with a littie bit of ringing, too.